# Dublin Core -- How do I indicate the email address of the creators?

Tags: meta-tags, dublin-core

How can I connect between creator and creator's address?

```html
<META NAME="DC.Creator" CONTENT="David S. H. Rosenthal"/>
<META NAME="DC.Creator" CONTENT="Thomas Robertson"/>
<META NAME="DC.Creator.Email" CONTENT="dshr@stanford.edu"/>
<META NAME="DC.Creator.Email" CONTENT="troberts@stanford.edu"/>
```

Comment: Where’s the name `DC.Creator.Email` from/defined? It doesn’t seem to be a Dublin Core property.

Comment: @unor I think that's what the question is asking...